# Triggered Send testing - how to exclude All Subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, triggered-send

We're using Triggered Sends for the first time.

We're triggering them using javascript triggered from a CloudPage.

As this is the first time we're using this type of send, we're slightly terrified of emailing people we shouldn't be when testing.  Therefore, we'd like to add an exclusion script to exclude anyone in All Subscribers (making sure of course that the requested email address in the test isn't in All Subscribers).

We've established how write a script to exclude people who are present in a Data Extension, but not in All Subscribers.

How exactly would we do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really wouldn't recommend this, as it is going to likely be slow - but as this is for testing only, you could reference the [_Subscribers Dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=0) in the lookup: `ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS('_Subscribers','SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey)) > 0`

This Dataview would contain the Subscriberkey of every subscriber in your email 'All Subscribers' list.

Another option I have used is to pause the trigger so that everything queues. You can then test that you are correctly passing the subscription information via the 'View Queue' button without sending any messages. You can then also preview the messages based on the data inside the Triggered Data Extension to verify email and AMPscript syntax. From there, you can then clear the queue and restart the Trigger so you can begin live tests once all that is approved.

Comment: Thanks, the pause idea will do the trick.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a great case for a Sandbox but MC does not have this function unfortunately. I know it won't solve your problem directly but what about requesting a demo environment for testing purposes as stated in this Knowledge Article: [Request a Demo environment for Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322291&type=1&mode=1)?

> Please reach out to your Account Executive to enable a demo
>   environment for your Marketing Cloud Account.   It is of note that
>   Marketing Cloud does not offer the same Sandbox functionality as
>   Salesforce Core.   Marketing Cloud demo environments do not mirror
>   Production accounts and any feature requests for Sandbox accounts
>   would be done separately as the Sandbox will be a stand alone account.

By having this environment it would be much easier for you to test some features without worrying that you might email production contacts.

Comment: Thank you, we don't have that option unfortunately.  We'll think of other ways around this!

Comment: I know it's not much but you can also vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ)